# Toggle to editing mode in View Controllers

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a View Controller that displays some labels. When entering in editing mode, I want them to change to `UITextField` in order to be editable. What is the cleanest way to do it?

So far, I have edited `(void)setEditing:(BOOL)flag animated:(BOOL)animated`. In my `.xib` I have both the `UILabel` and `UITextField` on above the other and when entering editing mode, I disable the hide the labels and show the text fields. But I was wondering if there is a wiser way to do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a UITableView to manage the view mode and edit more is cleaner than what you are doing currently.